# Copy attributes using .clone()

Tags: java, object, copy

I'm trying to copy int father_state[][], that it is copied using .clone() method of another Object class, to another same type int son_state[][], and when i trying to change the value of the son_state, the value of father_state changes too.

```
public Node create_node_son(Node father_node, String action, int row, int column){
                 Node new_node= new Nodo();
                 int father_state[][] = father_node.state.clone();
                 int son_state[][] = father_state;
                 int aux;

                 new_node.setState(father_node.state);

                 /*SWAP of states*/
                 aux = new_node.state[father_node.pos_zero_y][nodo_padre.pos_zero_x];
                 new_node.estado[father_node.pos_zero_y][father_node.pos_zero_x]= son_state[row][column];
                 new_node.estado[row][column]=aux;


                 //nuevo_nodo = new Nodo(estado_hijo, columna, renglon, nodo_padre.costo+1, accion, nodo_padre);
                 /*Refresh the data*/
                 new_node.action=action;
                 new_node.cost=nodo_father.costo+1;
                 new_node.father=nodo_father;
                 new_node.pos_zero_x=cloumn;
                 new_node.pos_zero_y=row;

                 return new_node;
             }
```

Comment: `int son_state[][] = father_state.clone();`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the state of son leads to change in father state because both are pointing to the same object as mentioned here:

```
             int son_state[][] = father_state;
```

You should have cloned the father_state for son also as mentioned here:

```
int father_state[][] = father_node.state.clone(); // new clone object
int son_state[][] = father_node.state.clone(); // new clone object
```

Comment: I have the same same result, father and son changes.

Comment: @DanielRiveraGuzman Not possible, update your code in question with the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another post, i was need another function to copy

```
public static int[][] cloneArray(int[][] src) {
    int length = src.length;
    int[][] target = new int[length][src[0].length];
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          System.arraycopy(src[i], 0, target[i], 0, src[i].length);
       }
    return target;
}
```